# The name 'filePath' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a variable, into another private void.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Get the path of specified file
           var filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        }
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(filePath);
}
```

**Question:**

How can I pass the variable filePath into another private void?

**Current output**

The name 'filePath' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Save it as a class attribute ?

Comment: This isn't just any "private void" (method) where you could maybe pass it as an argument; it's an event handler. Declare the variable at the class level so you can access it inside the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have defined filePath under `if` scope.  The variable will not be available outside that scope.

So you can declare a filePath variable at class level.

```
private string filePath = null;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Get the path of specified file
           filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        }
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string messageToShow = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) ? "No file selected": filePath;
    MessageBox.Show(messageToShow );
}
```

Comment: when I click the button, the messagebox is empty, after choosing the file?

Comment: You click the button1 after button2 click.

Comment: Edited answer, you can show alternative text if file is not selected.

Answer (score 2):

You variable currently has local scope, you need to make it a member variable.

```
// I've made the assumption you're creating a Windows Forms application.
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    string filePath;

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Get the path of specified file
                filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I click the button, the messagebox is empty, after choosing the file?

Comment: @98Ed You'll need to provide a minimal, complete example then because you've left something out. The code shown will display the file selected when executed in a Windows Forms application for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass it if you declare the variable inside that scope.
What you can do is set a member in your class and set it inside your if statement

```
private string _filePath = string.Empty;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Get the path of specified file
          _filePath  = openFileDialog.FileName;

        }
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filePath ) return;
    MessageBox.Show(_filePath);
}
```